# Rails Admin input mask [Rails 6]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, rails-admin

I need some inputs to have masks. Example: the phone field should be something like "(xxx) xxxxx-xxxx"

How can I include these "()" and "-" with masks.

My aplication uses Rails-Admin, and I tried to add some js and doesn't work when I acces ' /admin '

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a custom plugin for this i recommend [inputmask](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask) for jQuery because rails admin already includes jQuery.

Then you can include the library [inputmask.js](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask/blob/5.x/dist/inputmask.min.js) on

```
app/assets/javascripts/rails_admin/custom/inputmask.js
```

And the [bindings for automasking](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask/blob/5.x/dist/bindings/inputmask.binding.js) on

```
app/assets/javascripts/rails_admin/custom/inputmask.binding.js
```

And then add this file on your project

```
app/assets/javascripts/rails_admin/custom/ui.js
```

With this content

```
//= require_tree .
//= require 'rails_admin/custom/inputmask.js'
//= require 'rails_admin/custom/inputmask.binding.js'
```

Then is just a matter of configuring the field with the mask as the documentation of inputmask.js suggests something like this

```
  rails_admin do
    edit do
      field :phone do
        html_attributes do
          {
            'data-inputmask' => "'mask': '(999) - 99999-9999'"
          }
        end
      end
    end
```

I tried it on my project in it looks like this

[Screenshot of field with custom mask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQMjf.png)

Comment: I applied it to my code and inspecting the field I can see `<input class="form-control" data-inputmask=" mask: '(99) 99999-9999' " type="text" name="telefone[telefone]" id="telefone_telefone" wfd-id="56">`. It seems that the mask was applied in html, but it still hasn't given me the effect.

Comment: It does not work by itself, you need the inputmask library, are you sure it was included?

Comment: Yes. I has run " yarn add inputmask" that shoulded work, right?

Comment: I don't think that adds the bindings, you will have to do it manually check the library readme first part of usage section.

Comment: I dind't get it. Could you explaing? How I put manually? And in what file?

Comment: Read my answer again please, the file paths are in it.

Comment: I followed every single step and doesn't worked. 
Would you have any ideia of what can be done ?

Comment: Not sure, it seems like you used yarn instead of my recommended solution, at this point i have no idea what are you doing.

Comment: I did all steps, doesn't worked. And then I used 'yarn add' cause i thought I gonna needed. Nothing worked

Answer (score 0):

Struggled with this for a while as well, but this procedure finally worked:

1. Get the latest recommended version of this gem here and add to Gemfile:
   https://rubygems.org/gems/jquery-mask-plugin
2. Run bundle in terminal
3. Restart rails server
4. Add these lines (exactly as they are):

//= require jquery.inputmask

//= require jquery.inputmask.extensions

//= require jquery.inputmask.numeric.extensions

//= require jquery.inputmask.date.extensions

..in this folder in your project: app/assets/javascripts/application.js

5. Follow the instruction in the gem documentations for the method that suits you best: https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask
   (I used the jquery plugin)